# Can't get angular-bootstrap-select to work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-select

Because I want a sexy looking `<select>` in my angular website I'm trying to get [Angular-Bootstrap-Select](https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select) working. The demo seems fairly simple, but I just can't get it to work in my own code.

I import all dependencies without problems (jQuery, Bootstrap-select, Angular, etc.) and Bootstrap-select works perfectly fine outside of Angular.

I installed angular-bootstrap-select using bower, import it successfully in the head and inject it in my angular app:

```
var propertyApp = angular.module('propertyApp', [
    'propertyControllers',
    'ui.router',
    'angular-bootstrap-select'
]);

propertyApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $stateProvider
            .state('new', {
                url: '/new',
                templateUrl: '/static/angular/property/partials/newProperty.html',
                controller: 'NewPropertyCtrl'
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/new')
    }
]);
```

My controller is completely empty:

```
var propertyControllers = angular.module('propertyControllers', []);
propertyControllers.controller('NewPropertyCtrl', [function(){
}]);
```

and my template looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        Before selectpicker
        <select class="selectpicker">
            <option>Mustard</option>
            <option>Ketchup</option>
            <option>Relish</option>
        </select>
        After selectpicker
    </div>
</div>
```

but the only thing I see in the browser is: `Before selectpicker After selectpicker`.

I've got a [working codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojXwVg?editors=101), but I just can't figure out what is so different between that example, and my own code.

Does anybody see or maybe know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]

I can get it to work perfectly well [in a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyXQgw?editors=101), but in my own code it still won't to work. My own test is here: http://185.53.129.139:5000/property-admin#/new This really drives me crazy, so anybody helping me out with this would really make my day!

Comment: You must call `$('.select').selectpicker();` in `onInit()` method as first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small plunker I've made with bootstrap-select and angular.
http://plnkr.co/edit/webnjq6kzLDnnkI9ZO6W

```
  angular.module('angular-bootstrap-select', [])
  .directive('selectpicker', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.selectpicker($parse(attrs.selectpicker)());
        element.selectpicker('refresh');

        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newVal, oldVal) {
          scope.$parent[attrs.ngModel] = newVal;
          scope.$evalAsync(function () {
            if (!attrs.ngOptions || /track by/.test(attrs.ngOptions)) element.val(newVal);
            element.selectpicker('refresh');
          });
        });

    scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
      scope.$evalAsync(function () {
        element.selectpicker('destroy');
      });
    });
  }
};
}]);
```

As you'll see, bootstrap-select is wrapped in a directive. I think that's the easies way.

Regards,
Eric

Comment: Okay, I messaed around with it for hours now, and I still can't get it to work. I created a codepen which comes really close to my own code here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyXQgw?editors=101 . That works, but in my own code it still doesn't work. The only difference now seems to be that I use a $stateProvider and a separate url for the template. Maybe you can check my own test and see what I do wrong? The url is: http://185.53.129.139:5000/property-admin#/new . You would really make my day if you can solve this!

Comment: Could I see your html used for your own test on 185.53.129.139? P.S. you are loading angular multiple time on your test. That's probably not the issue but that can't be good.

Comment: From what I saw it's probably a dependency injection issue. Are you injecting 'angular-bootstrap-select' is your controller?

Comment: I don't inject it in the controller no. This is also not done in the working codepen. I simply added it as a `angular.module(..`. I removed the double loading of angular, but (as expected) that doesn't solve anything. You can check out my app.js at http://185.53.129.139:5000/static/angular/property/js/app.js and my controllers.js at http://185.53.129.139:5000/static/angular/property/js/controllers.js and my html template at  http://185.53.129.139:5000/static/angular/property/partials/newProperty.html Do you have any idea if you check out my code?

Comment: Hi, the directive is "restrict:'A'" and in your view you have  <select class="selectpicker"> have you tried <select selectpicker=""> instead?

Comment: It works!! But.... why?!? What does `restrict:'A'` mean? And why does it say `class="selectpicker"` in the docs?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive : `restrict:'A'` only matches attribute name